# Sending mails with php

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send email with my php script and i have been trying the normal format

```
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

having pre-defined $to, $subject, $message as variables, but does not work, have tried changing my php.ini to

```
 [mail function]
 ; For Win32 only.
 XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 ; http://php.net/smtp
 SMTP = localhost
 ; http://php.net/smtp-port
 smtp_port = 25

 ; For Win32 only.
 ; http://php.net/sendmail-from
 sendmail_from = something@gmail.com
```

as some examples online told me , but all to no avail, please what does this frustrating activity entail?

Comment: Define: 'does not work'. Do you get an error? What is the result (var_dump) of the mail function? etc

Comment: The funny thing - i put it in an if statement, that if it does send it should echo something otherwise it echos the message like it actually sends, meanwhile it does not how can i make it produce an error message

Comment: Why there is no semicolon before this line `XAMPP: Comment out this if...` ? Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a SMTP lib for this, [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is the best choice. Notice that u're trying to use it with Gmail, so you may want to check this example: [gmail-example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)